# How to hide an «Annoying Element» with appium

Tags: python, android-studio, appium

Sometimes it happens that an element in the work is very annoying and its absence is better.
In Selenium below is the code I use to hide the annoying elements.

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("{}").style.display = "none";'.format('div.xvbhtw8.x1lq5wgf.xgqcy7u.x30kzoy.x9jhf4c.x1rj4ezl.x1n2onr6.xfr5jun.xexx8yu.x4uap5. x18d9i69.xkhd6sd'))
```

In fact, I manually set the «-- **display** --» **Tag** of that element in css as **“none”**.

But this method doesn’t work in appium!
**Does anyone know a way to hide an element?**